# How to get a value from specific cell address in Excel through Laravel

Tags: excel, laravel

Is there any way to get the cell value with exact address in Excel?

Like I upload the excel file then return sheet(2).cell(10,1).value ?

Since I am writing a website to upload a excel and put those data into DB,
the file's rows and columns are automatically generated and the formats are not exactly matching maatwebsite/Excel's upload sample.

I am using Laravel 5.7 and maatwebsite/Excel 3.1

Comment: Can you show, what you have tried?

Comment: Please see Daniel's reply , he gave the ans, thanks for your comment~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In maatwebsite/Excel 2.* you could fetch the value in the cell with

```
Excel::load('file.xlsx, function($excel) {
    $cell = $excel->getSheet(2)->getCellByColumnAndRow(10, 1);       
});
```

These methods have been removed in 3.*

However `maatwebsite/Excel` is just a  wrapper around `phpoffice/phpspreadsheet` - so we can still call the function directly from that library:

```
$inputFileName = 'filename.xlsx';

$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($inputFileName);

$cellValue = $spreadsheet->getSheet(2)->getCellByColumnAndRow(10, 1)->getValue();
```

Comment: it's not work for version 3.1...
The load method is not exsist~

Comment: Thanks you so much! I just found out they use PhpOffice but not able to find out they use that way to read the sheet!

Answer (score 1):

I hope [this](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/basics.html) would be help to you.

Comment: thanks for your help but it's not work...
i would like to get the value in exact address